# Receive a shell command as an OptionParser string argument

Tags: python, shell, optionparser

I am using OptionParser(), and define the following:

```
parser.add_option("--cmd", dest="command", help="command to run")
```

However, if i provide a complex shell command, such as :

```
python shell.py --cmd "for i in `seq 1 10`; do xxx; done"
```

And internally print `options.command`, i get something unexpected to me:

```
for i in 1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10; do
```

Is there a good way to pass an OptionParser option which is a shell command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When invoking:

```
python shell.py --cmd "for i in `seq 1 10`; do xxx; done"
```

The shell first substitute the command enclosed in ` with its output. Thus, the command you actually invoke is:

```
python shell.py --cmd "for i in 1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10; do ..."
```

---

To avoid this:

Escape the ` character when invoking the command:

```
python shell.py --cmd "for i in \`seq 1 10\`; do xxx; done"
```

Use strong quoting (string enclosed in ')

```
python shell.py --cmd 'for i in `seq 1 10`; do xxx; done'
```

Comment: I don't want to use escapes in the input command,  there are more special characters in the extended command that `, is that still possible?

Comment: It is related to your shell more than python. Try to use ' instead of "